# Error message when writing dataframe to excel

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I am loading a pkl file into a dataframe and want to save it to excel using Excelwriter from pandas. Loading of the pkl file into a DF works fine, writing the frame to excel throws following error:

> ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value)

I do not know what is wrong.

I have anaconda with python 3.7 installed on one computer where the code works fine and runs without problems. However, on a different computer (with python 3.7 and freshly installed pandas and pickle), it fails... any help is appreciated!

The pkl file is a file that has sorted academic litterature in it - so nothing exciting.

```
import pickle
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

def open_pickle():
    savename = 'neuro_10_neuron[TIAB]_19-02-19'
    try:
        with open(savename + '.pkl', 'rb') as f:
            holder = pickle.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('Cannot find it!')

    framed =  pd.DataFrame.from_dict(holder)

    writer = ExcelWriter(savename + '.xlsx')
    framed.to_excel(writer)
    writer.save()

open_pickle()
```

Thanks in advance!

Below you find a picture of the entire error message. Maybe that points someone into a direction that might help me...
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for me the modification of the code after intstalling the *xlsxwriter* module solved it. Code now looks like this:

```
import pickle
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter


def open_pickle():
    savename = 'neuro_10_neuron[TIAB] AND 2018[PDAT]_01-03-19'
    try:
        with open(savename + '.pkl', 'rb') as f:
            holder = pickle.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('Cannot find it!')

    framed =  pd.DataFrame.from_dict(holder)

    writer = ExcelWriter(savename + '.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    framed.to_excel(writer)
    writer.save()

    return(framed)

a= open_pickle()
```

Hope that helps, if anyone ever comes across something like this.
Cheers